# Email full of Greater Than > and Less Than < Symbols <><><>

Tags: vb.net, email, html-email, smtpclient

I am having a hard time phrasing this question properly, which is probably why I cannot find any Google results for it.  Basically, I have a VB.NET program which automatically generates and sends email with the System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.

Some people (a small percentage) are unable to view these emails.  They say that the email body is full of GT and LS symbols like this <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><

I am 100% sure that this is something on the client side (perhaps with their email client or browser).  I just basically need to let them know what to do to fix it.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like their company doesn't allow HTML emails or strips the content out of HTML emails for security purposes. If you test with them, do HTML emails fail to render and plain text work ok?

Answer (score 1):

E-mailing an HTML email is tricky business; there are all sorts of different tags that don't quite work and there are other things you can include that will almost certainly trigger some sort of security measure or filter.

Sites like [Litmus](http://www.litmus.com) are designed to help you test your email in several different clients, and also give a rundown of [best practices](https://litmus.com/blog/html-email-coding-101-infographic) for HTML emails; among them include:

- Don't use CSS positioning or clearing
- Stick to inline styles and don't reference external CSS
- Avoid any 'shorthand' HTML
- Limit your image usage
- If you must have images, include your alt tags

If the recipient's mail server is using something like [SpamAssassin](http://spamassassin.apache.org/), even your content could trigger a spam filter (mentioning money back guarantees, large amounts of money, etc)

Lastly, you can use a tool like [Premailer](http://premailer.dialect.ca/) to help trim down your HTML and hopefully avoid any snafus.

Without knowing what exactly your e-mail contains, we can't do too much to help on that front, but the points above are a good starting place if you want to clean up your content!